# Version 2: How can I write a postgres sql query that returns M distinct values of a certain column with M + unknown overall records returned?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is a slightly harder version of what I posted earlier. I don't want to edit the original to ruin a perfectly good answer to the question I had at the time.

Suppose a table named tau.

```
tau:
A | B | C
----------    
2 - 1 - red
3 - 1 - rod
4 - 1 - rope
6 - 5 - red
7 - 5 - rap
8 - 5 - rod
9 - 10 -rod
11- 10 -road
12- 13 -rud
```

Column A is the primary key. It will be unique. Column B is a foreign key. In my database no integer key is ever the same across tables. Column C is not a key.

This table will have a lot of rows. There are many other columns, say column C for instance, that are indexed for search.

I want exactly M distinct values from column B. Lets say M = 2

Importantly, I am using column B in the expression (it's indexed too!) to determine which B's to return.

Normally, I would go

```
select distinct B From tau Where C like 'r_d' AND B < 13 Order By B Desc Limit 2
```

and I get

```
B
-----
10
5
```

This is the current state of affairs, now. But I want to upgrade to a new scenario:

When the expression on B C is satisfied and adds the record to the results pile (C like 'r_d' AND B < 13), I want to return column A as well as column B, **while maintaining the restriction of 2 at most distinct column B values.**

**Another important condition is the solution must work for expressions in the where clause that return true for possibly different values of C.**

Behold, the results I want.

```
A | B
------
9 - 10
8 - 5
6 - 5
```

The trouble is, the actual limit of records returned can be greater than M, or 2 in the example. I don't really care how many records come through, as long as there are only M distinct values of B. How would I write a query to accomplish this in Postgresql?

Comment: So, you don't have a search criteria for the `B` column, right? Your search criteria is for other columns, you get some long result set, but then you want to limit that result set to have only two distinct values in `B`. Which `B` values would you like to pick? Random two? Last two ordered by `B`?

Comment: In my case I actually am using B in the expression , like B < 10, to stipulate which B's to return. That is an important point, I'll add it. See updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DENSE_RANK`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-window.html) should do what you need. Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/860ac/2/0).
Put your `M` into `WHERE R.rnk <= 2` instead of `2`.

Rather than starting with `M` distinct values from `B` and trying to figure out how to add missing values from column `A` to the final result, I'm thinking about this problem from the other side. We have some search conditions that limit the whole table to some intermediary result set:

```
SELECT *
FROM tau
WHERE C LIKE 'r_d' AND B < 13
```

This intermediary result set has all columns from the table, nothing is aggregated yet. We just need to filter this set further and leave only `M` distinct values of the `B` column. `DENSE_RANK` assigns a number (without gaps) to each group of `B` values, so we can use it in the final filter.

```
SELECT
    A, B
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A
            ,B
            ,C
            ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY B DESC) AS rnk
        FROM tau
        WHERE C LIKE 'r_d' AND B < 13
    ) AS R
WHERE R.rnk <= 2
ORDER BY B DESC, A DESC;
```

**result set**

```
A    B
9    10
8    5
6    5
```

**Second variant using LATERAL JOIN**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/860ac/13/1) with both variants.
In the second variant we are finding `M` distinct values of `B` at first. Then for each found value we run the main query with extra filter for this `B` value. If there are millions of different values of `B`, then filtering to specific value should be efficient, provided there is an index on `B`. If there are millions of rows, but number of total distinct values of `B` is small, it should be slow.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    select distinct B 
    From tau 
    Where C like 'r_d' AND B < 13 
    Order By B Desc 
    Limit 2
)
SELECT
  T.A, T.B, T.C
FROM
  CTE
  INNER JOIN LATERAL
  (
      SELECT tau.A, tau.B, tau.C
      FROM tau
      WHERE tau.B = CTE.B AND tau.C like 'r_d' AND tau.B < 13 
  ) AS T ON true
ORDER BY T.B DESC, T.A DESC;
```

Comment: How fast is this if everything is indexed properly?

Comment: i updated your fiddle already, unless you did it concurrently. Are fiddles owned? Sorry for switching the example on you I figured I needed to exclude a record with the limit 2.

Comment: I edited the fiddle and updated the link in the answer. I think when you change the fiddle the link changes. The query can't be faster than the main `SELECT ... WHERE C LIKE 'r_d' AND B < 13`. `DENSE_RANK` will walk through this temporary result set and calculate the rank, finally extra filter would remove ranks more than 2. If that final filter removes 99% of the result set, maybe there are ways to make it faster without generating the whole temporary result set. I don't know if Postgres query optimizer is smart enough.

Comment: That is a very clever solution. I've never used Dense_Rank before.

Comment: `DENSE_RANK` seems to do exactly what you are asking for here. Your question is in a sense a definition of this function. No extra tricks or extra steps needed.

Comment: Basically, what I'm doing is printing out all A's that belong to the limited groups B that are displayed. But I want to mark which A's had the C's that triggered the B's to be included originally. That way when I print out the records these satisfying records can be highlighted. So after this query I have to run another one.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is slow. The intermediary result set needs to be limited to ideally no more than M distinct values of B, otherwise, the query takes forever. This will have millions of rows. So we seem to have ourselves a problem! I will try to cook up another solution.

Comment: In this case you need to find a way to find `M` values of `B` fast at first. Then, when you have specific values for `B` you can search for them in the large table. Does your original simple query `SELECT DISTINCT B` run fast?

Comment: Yeah, it's really fast. I like it. The only trouble is showing the user which records triggered the B hit.

Comment: I guess I'd find the M values of B in query one with my original query, then change my B where condition to an IN list or two greater than / less than statements in this query, then run the third query. Shouldn't be more than 15 ms of a penalty once the server gets spun up.

Comment: Added second variant with `lateral join`. There has to be an index on `B` for it to be efficient.

Comment: doing the extra query so far adds 2-5 ms. theoretically the lateral join would eliminate a roundtrip so it could be faster. I'll have to try it sometime. Thanks for all your help Vlada